# How to implement ELK with Wso2 APIM 4.2 in AKS

Tags: elasticsearch, wso2, azure-aks, wso2-api-manager, elk

I am yet to deploy wso2 API manger 4.2 in AKS, So the plan is to setup ELK for monitoring API, so can anybody provide the best practice or method to implement elk with wso2 APIM in AKS. OR is there any service in Azure so that we can use it in this situation.

The hiccup is how the push the api_metric.log from wso2 apim which is running in AKS node to ELK.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

By following the APIM ELK analytics guide, the logs will be published into a separate log file, you can write the analytics logs to the pods log by changing the log4j2.properties file and, run a filebeats as a daemonset and push logs from the pods to the ELK cluster.